# Best way to test my website landing while developing for mobile

Tags: css, mobile

I try to develop my website for mobile landing but I do not know how to test its standing on my computer. Do you know any tool or website that might help for testing the website landing on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

For responsive design you can use one of these:

http://screenqueri.es/

http://www.responsinator.com/

Or if you're doing it the old-fashioned way (user agents) then you can use a [Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) and test your website in the browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

For testing responsive websites use one of these:

1) http://responsive.is

2) http://screenqueri.es

3) or use Adobe Shadow: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-shadow/id498621426?mt=8